# Spring: extract criterias from QuerydslPredicate

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data

I perform a search with a predicate:
`public void myFilter(@QuerydslPredicate(root = MyEntity.class) Predicate predicate)`.
The `MyEntity` class has some fields: field1, field2, etc.
I'd like to log the fact I'm filtering on a specific field (and its value(s)). How can I get this information?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: `List<Expression<?>> args = ((PredicateOperation) predicate).getArgs();` returns filter arguments.